# How to allow the user to copy items from listbox and paste outside of windows form

Tags: c#

I know that, for data grids, users can select the items, copy them, and then paste them outside of the form. Is there was a way to do that with listboxes? It looks like you can select multiple items in the listbox but it doesn't appear that it actually copies it if you try to paste the selected values outside of the form.

Comment: What do you mean by *" paste them outside of the form"*?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway if they had a word document up they would be able to paste the selected values that they copied to it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can catch the event when user click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to put the item to the clipboard.

This code is for the list box with multi-selection `MultiSimple=true`

```
private void ListBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder copy_buffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (object item in ListBox1.SelectedItems)
                copy_buffer.AppendLine(item.ToString());
            if (copy_buffer.Length > 0)
                Clipboard.SetText(copy_buffer.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help you!!

Comment: With the newer versions of .Net you may run into problems with `Clipboard.SetText()` (random errors that won't mean much). Use `Clipboard.SetDataObject()` instead.

Comment: You may wish to prevent the default handling of the key (the `C` key in this case) with code like this `e.SuppressKeyPress = true; e.Handled = true;` so it doesn't jump to the next item in the list that begins with C.

Answer (score 2):

To copy selected item via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> use this code:

```
private void LstVehicles_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.C))
   {
      Clipboard.SetText(this.yourListBoxName.SelectedItem.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 solutions didn't work for me, what did work was though clicking on the listBox, and generating a function called

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

inside I put...

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

So the complete solution was

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

So did get a line from one of the solutions and one of the comments.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can select only one line in the listbox, I know it not the best,
but by code below left mouse click copy all the listbox Items
to the Clipboard:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder copy_buffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            copy_buffer.AppendLine(item.ToString());
        if (copy_buffer.Length > 0)
            Clipboard.SetText(copy_buffer.ToString());
    }
```